# Compare two string and remove common letters

Tags: c, string, compare, character

I am having problem with an exercise, so here is the exercise:

> Write a program that aids with appropriate messages on the screen to read two character strings `str1` and `str2` even which will be given from the keyboard, and then delete all the letters in the variable `str1`, which also appear in the variable `str2`. The display shows the final result for checking the correct operation of the program.

And here is what I have done so far (I can use only these libraries):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[80], str2[80];
    int megethos1, megethos2,max,i,j;
    printf ("Give the first string: ");
    scanf ("%s", &str1);
    printf ("Give the second string: ");
    scanf ("%s", &str2);

    size1= strlen(str1);
    size2= strlen(str2);

    for (j=0; j<=megethos2; j++){
        for (i=0; i<=megethos1; i++){
             if (str2[(strlen(str2)-j)]=str1[(strlen(str1)-i)])
                 str1[(strlen(str1)-i)]=' ';
        }
    }

    printf (str1);

    system("pause");

}
```

So anyone can help me?

Comment: Is there a problem with what you've coded so far?  Does it not work?  What behavior does it have?

Comment: you are using c, not c#.

Comment: Also, tags don't belong in the title, and "I" is written with a capital letter.

Comment: I see you've learned about strlen.  There are many other string-handling function in the standard library - in particular, I recommend you reads the docs for strpbrk, strspn, strcspn, and strchr.  While you're in there, scout around for other interesting functions which may help you with later assignments.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str1[80], str2[80];
    int size1,size2, i,j;
    printf ("Give the first string: ");
    scanf ("%s", str1);
    printf ("Give the second string: ");
    scanf ("%s", str2);

    size1= strlen(str1);
    size2= strlen(str2);

    for (j=0; j<size2; j++){
        for (i=0; i<size1; i++){
             if (str2[j]==str1[i])
                 str1[i]=' ';
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", str1);

    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     if (str2[(strlen(str2)-j)]=str1[(strlen(str1)-i)])
         str1[(strlen(str1)-i)]=' ';
```

When `i` is `0` then `str2[(strlen(str1)]` is the terminating null character of the string that you are overwriting with `' '`. You need a `- 1` somewhere.

As [@PaulR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) noted in the comments, the first `=` should be a `==`.

Also note that you have to use `scanf("%s", str)` and not `scanf("%s", &str)`.

Comment: Also note that the first `=` should probably be a `==` ?

Answer (score -1):

Is your question about C or C#?

For C# you can use LINQ:

```
var s1 = "string new";
var s2 = "string";

var excludedCharText =
  s1
    .Where(c => s2.All(o => o != c))
    .Select(c => c.ToString())
    .Aggregate((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

Comment: I think your whole answer is a horribly slow substitute for `new string(s1.Except(s2).ToArray())` (which is already quite inefficient). Look at string builder if you wanted something a bit more efficient